# Can I configure Quartz to prevent jobs from running on a particular node?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I'm using Quartz 1.6 in a clustered environment and am having some resource issues.  Consequently, I want to prevent certain nodes from running any background/scheduled jobs.

Quartz is currently configured using the `org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX`, and all my nodes launch the scheduler on startup.

```
  org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
  org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.MSSQLDelegate
  org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
  org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = QUARTZ
  org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false
  org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
  org.quartz.dataSource.QUARTZ.jndiURL = java:/AppDB
```

Is there some configuration parameter that I could pass to disable a node from processing any background jobs?  Or to specify which node(s) I want jobs to run on?

I thought I could "trick" Quartz by setting my threadCount to 0, but unfortunately that doesn't work.

Are there other config parameters I could use instead?

Comment: Why does decreasing the threadcount not work? I think this is the best way to solve such resource issues.

Comment: @mam10eks Unfortunately quartz expects threadCount > 0

Comment: I think that makes sense, since a threadCount of size zero would mean that there will never be a job running on that SchedulerInstance (i.e. the Scheduler will always be idle). Hence quartz doesnt even start a SchedulerInstance with such a configuration.

Comment: Between: I have just seen that the property `org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered` is set to `false`. Is that just a typing error in the above post or is that the real configuration of each SchedulerInstance in the cluster?

Comment: @mam10eks cut & paste error.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to have SchedulerInstances that are always idle (i.e. threadCount = 0)? Or do you want to do some partitioning of the cluster, for example some nodes could only execute "lightweight" jobs and other nodes could execute "expensive" jobs too?

Comment: @mam10eks Yes - right now I have some background jobs that are very resource intensive and need to segregate them off some servers.  To accomplish this quickly without having to redeploy (and change the code that starts the scheduler), I thought I could maybe just play with the config params, setting the thread count to 0.  Unfortunately (understandably), Quartz doesn't allow that.  Is there another way I can target jobs in a cluster to specific nodes or away from other ones?

Comment: Ok, instead of setting the threadCount to 0 you could just change the SchedulerName of that instances. After that they will act in a own logical cluster and will not run any jobs of the other SchedulerInstances.

Comment: @mam10eks Thanks for the suggestion; will try that out on Monday.  Is there a way I can have jobs target different clusters?

Comment: A job is automatically assigned to that cluster, on which you create the job (but as a dirty trick you could change that setting after job-creation within the persistence layer , i.e. your database)